# What does this if statement do?

Tags: matlab

I have this piece of code that I'm trying understand what is going on.

So can anyone tell me what this if statement does in math?

```
prob = exp(-dE / kT);

if dE <= 0 I I rand() <= prob;

spin(row, col) = - spin(row, col);
```

Comment: the I's are bars. Other than that should be good no? Its not my program but it runs. Of course an end is missing too.

Answer (score 3):

That's not valid MATLAB syntax. So what it does is give you a syntax error. You probably meant

```
prob = exp(-dE / kT);
if dE <= 0 || rand() <= prob
    spin(row, col) = - spin(row, col);
end
```

which gives you a probability based on an exponential function (the Boltzmann distribution), and *if* your change in energy, `dE`, is smaller than or equal to zero (thus energy is lost), **or** your probability is higher than or equal to a randomly generated number between 0 and 1, the spin at location `(row,col)` in your matrix is inversed, i.e. multiplied with `-1`.

Comment: @obchardon it's not super polite or useful to edit someone's answer just to remove something which has no effect. I could edit Adriaan's code and remove all the spaces because they too are useless, but there's no reason to do so... The OP had included a semi-colon in their code, so this answer simply preserved that for continuity.

Comment: @Wolfie In my opinion it's useful to preserve a continuity in a code syntax to make 
things clear. It avoid that people keep a bad habit. It was by no means unpolite.